Detect certain elements of screen using pyautogui
So I am trying to make an autotyping bot that's reactive. I keep trying to locate a photo on screen but it will keep print the same answer on screen forever even if the conditions have changed.
import pyautogui
import time
import keyboard

time.sleep(2)


numbs = 0
neg_numbs = 0


while True:
  if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):
    print('Stopping loop')
    break
  if pyautogui.locateAllOnScreen('characters/e.png'):
    numbs = numbs + 1
    print('I can see it',numbs)
    time.sleep(.5)
  else:
    neg_numbs = neg_numbs + 1
    print('I am unable to see it',neg_numbs)
    time.sleep(.5)


There is a photo the the text cursor I am trying to locate in a folder called characters in the filename cursor.png.
I expected maybe for the answer to change but when the conditions(The content of the screen changes) the answer will not change. I am currently using the latest version of pyautogui. To find the image of the cursor I use the locateAllOnScreen function because the locateOnScreen function is depricated. Do y'all know what I can do to fix this?
